# How to trigger a DataStage job once a SQL server job has completed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datastage

Currently there is a job in SQL server that is scheduled to runs several times a day.

The SQL Job builds a file for the DataStage job that is scheduled shortly after the SQL server job, problem being that if the SQL job hasn't finished building the file, the DataStage job fails.

Is there a trigger/query that can be added on SQL server to trigger DataStage job?

Comment: Have you tried to call the DataStage job in the last step of the first job?

Comment: I am not even sure the syntax of calling a DataStage job from SQL, this would be the ideal solution

Comment: Did you try searching for documentation? Like [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.cliapi.ref.doc/topics/r_dsvjbref_Commands_for_Controlling_WebSphere_DataStage_Jobs.html)

Comment: That is not syntax for SQL, that is dsjob, as suggest by Michael. I Have been looking at using dsjob and will reply if it works when I finally get round to implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple solutions are possible:

1. Start the DataStage job from command line (via dsjob) and schedule this job in the same scheduler (as the SQL server job) after that job  (or schedule both in another common scheduler)
2. Use a wait for file stage in the DataStage Sequence. This could be configured to wait some time for the file.
3. Trigger the execution from a database trigger - I have done it for Db2 but it should be possible for you as well - maybe you have to write some code for that...

Comment: Thank you Michael, I used your first suggestion (dsjob). I could pass the required parameters and execute dsjob through a power shell script, which can then be executed within a SQL Server job.

Answer (score 0):

Have the SQL Server job create two files, the real file then a second "trigger" file. It can even be empty. DataStage detects the existence of the trigger file, which was not created until the real file was complete, then processes the real file.